# How to make a dependency property static?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dependency property called xpos with binding to a textbox. I was able to dynamically display the value of my dependency property on the textbox with no problem. However I have an arduino which I am talking to serially. I use another thread to read any incoming data. In this thread some data that comes is suppose to change the my dependency property. The problem is that the function the thread runs is static and the dependency property is not static. I can't call the property in this function.

I tried to make the property static but that created other errors.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Width="50" Height="20"
         Margin="12.4,10,0,10"
         Name="Xdisplay"
         Text="{Binding xpos, ElementName=CurrentWindow}"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         TextChanged="Xdisplay_TextChanged"/>
```

```
Thread Readthread = new Thread(Read);
public static bool _continue = true;
public static SerialPort com;

com.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(Rates.Text);
com.PortName = Ports.
com.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful");
Readthread.Start();


public static readonly DependencyProperty xposproperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(xpos), typeof(float), typeof(Window), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public float xpos
{
    get => (float)GetValue(xposproperty);
    set => SetValue(xposproperty, value);
}

public static void Read()
{
    while (_continue)
        try
        {
            string message = com.ReadLine();

            if (message.Contains("max limit reached"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(message);

                switch (message)
                {
                    case "x":
                        max = true;
                        xpos = int.Parse(message.Substring(20, message.Length));
                        break;
                    case "y":
                        ypos = int.Parse(message.Substring(20, message.Length));
                        break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency properties aren't the best thing for this, in WPF 4.5 you can [bind directly to static properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/whats-new#static_properties) instead:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

    private static double _XPos;
    public static double XPos
    {
        get { return _XPos; }
        set
        {
            if (_XPos != value)
            {
                _XPos = value;
                StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("XPos"));
            }
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // simulate values being read by the serial port
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
                XPos = rng.Next();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to drop the static properties altogether, put everything in a regular class instance and use dependency injection to make it a singleton, but the above will also work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mark! Does this code update the textbox as xpos changes its value?

Comment: What is the "?" in the StaticPropertyChanged line do?

Comment: Yes, the textbox will update when the static property does. The ? causes the event to only be invoked if there's something subscribed to it, it's basically the same as `if (StaticPropertyChanged != null) StaticPropertyChanged.Invoke(...)`.

Comment: Its not working and I believe it is where I placed the event and the static property. Should I have it inside the namespace and inside the MainWindow : Window Class?

Comment: That's up to you. Ordinarily you would put it in your View Model , or whatever else your MainWindow's DataContext is set to. You can also put it in your main window class if you like, but then you'll have to point the binding there instead.

Comment: Might be helpful to read up on [WPF data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf) before going any further.